# Эхо сервер на php

Tags: php, сокет, сервер, echo

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые обитатели ХэшКод. Пытаюсь написать простенький сокет-эхо сервер на php.
да что там, просто копипащу код с http://www.php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Позволяет скрипту ожидать соединения бесконечно. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Включает скрытое очищение вывода так что мы получаем данные
 * как только они появляются. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = 'localhost';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_create(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_bind(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_listen(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_accept(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Отправляем инструкции. */
    $msg = "\nДобро пожаловать на тестовый сервер PHP. \n" .
        "Чтобы отключиться, наберите 'выход'. Чтобы выключить сервер, наберите 'выключение'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_read(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'выход') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'выключение') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: Вы сказали '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Запускаю этот скрипт ( http://localhost/server.php ) - он ничего не выводит, просто, бесконечно грузится.
Ладно, пытаюсь в соседнем окошке браузера перейти по адресу http://localhost:10000  - нифига.
Как и советуют в статье, открываю терминал и ввожу:

```
$ telnet localhost 10000
```

в ответ вижу:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'
```

.

И... всё. Что не так?

Comment: Да вроде все так же. А что вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: попробуйте чтонить в терминал-то ввести) он же ввода ждет

Comment: :~$ telnet localhost 10000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello!
HELLO!!!
...  


Я пытался. Он хранит молчание

Comment: Я попробовал в 

    Linux avp-ubu1 3.2.0-49-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 17:39:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l


и он работает. 

Почему-то проблема с русской буквой 'х' в слове "выход" в telnet (очевидно PHP тут ни при чем), а вот с `ncat localhost 10000` все ОК.

А вот после

    if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsoc....
      ...

наверное вместо 

              break 2

лучше просто 

              break

Ну, возможно надо errno (или как там в PHP) проверить, если просто клиент разорвал соединение, то считать как команду "выход".

Comment: Linux localhost 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 17 21:43:33 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l

localhost почему-то просто молчит, игнорирую telnet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще как бы этот пример рабочий вот я прям с вашего кода вывел на тест единственное что у меня что-то видно с кодировкой т.к. ответы очень странные: http://youtu.be/If_dguRmKVs

Comment: Спасибо за видео! =D

Как вы думаете, почему не запускается у меня? ( ubuntu 13.04 )

Comment: тоже 13.04 то что на видео. Не знаю может както апач и php по особенному настроен